# Deploying an nodejs app to EC2 and update methods

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

So I have a node js app I would like to deploy to EC2.

I'm planning on creating multiple instances of it and put it beyond Nginx for load balancing.

I know I can use AWS Beanstalk but I think it's over provisioning stuff I don't need.

My question is about the app update process. I thought of two options.

The first one is to create a bare git repository on the EC2 and every time I push some changes, it will hook into the after receive event, create new instances of the app and update Nginx to switch to the new instances.

Another option is to work with Amazon ECR and containers. Every time I update my app image at ECR, it will send an event to the EC2 machine (I'm not sure it is even possiable) to create new instances of the app and again, tell the Nginx to switch.

Which one do you think is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the deployment method we used

1)Created git bare repo in ec2 server and its tracked with production branch.

2)in the `post-receive` hook

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
cd /var/www/domain.com && npm install && forever restart app.js
```

3)In the nginx configuration

```
 {
     proxy_pass:https://localhost:3000
  }
```

Note:
 You can customise post hook to check if its first deployment then run `npm install` otherwise run `npm update`.

I hope this will help to solve your issues

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful. Do you use any scaling? when you do the app restart, will it lose all the of its current connection? Thanks again

Comment: when a restart is occurs there was small delay is occurs but it can be managed by nginx